# How to write .indexOn for dynamic keys in firebase?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have data set up like this:

```
Tasks:{
  Group 1:{
    pushid1:{
      date: 18921949021,
      title: "Do something"
    },
    pushid2:{
      date: 18921949021,
      title: "Do something else"
    }
  },
  Group 2:{
    pushid3:{
      date: 18921949021,
      title: "Do another thing"
    }
  }
}
```

I reference it by date so I only get the tasks made after a certain time.

```
var now = Date.now();
var taskRef = new Firebase(FB + "/tasks/" + thisGroup);
taskRef.orderByChild('date').startAt(now).on("child_added", function(snap){
  console.log(snap.val());
});
```

This all works fine, for each group I get a warning message saying something like this:

```
FIREBASE WARNING: Using an unspecified index.  Consider adding ".indexOn": "date" at tasks/Group 1 to your security rules for better performance
```

How do I add that to my security rules?  I can't add one for each group a user makes, is there a wild card entry of some type?

Comment: Hi Marty. Have you ever solved this? Or decided to change the structure? Thanks

Comment: @jovanjovanovic Frank's answer worked for me.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

I guess you're looking for:

```
{
  ".read": true,
  ".write": true,
  "rules": {
    "Tasks": {
      "$groupid": {
        ".indexOn": "date"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The Firebase documentation is usually a pretty good read. Spending an hour or less in the [security guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/securing-data), will ensure you have a better understanding of this and many other topics.

Comment: I'm still getting "FIREBASE WARNING: Using an unspecified index. Consider adding ".indexOn": "clinics/1/date" at /requests to your security rules for better performance "

Comment: I got the similar issue with two level on authentication provider (e.g. google, twitter) and the ID (e.g. email). Both I can't hard code, what option do I have to index by the leaf elements, when two level of parent we can't hard code. Appreciate any help

Comment: @marty-h The `$groupid` was the wild card entry that the asker was asking for.

Comment: Same issue here, did you fix it @Steve

Answer (score 1):

I used Frank's answer, but it was giving me error,

```
Error saving rules - Line 1: Expected 'rules' property.
```

So, this worked for me:

```
{
  "rules": {
  ".read": true,
  ".write": true,
    "Tasks": {
      "$groupid": {
        ".indexOn": "date"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Screenshot of my Database rules:
[image]